# Can I upgrade Laravel 5.7 from Laravel 5.0 directly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have many applications built with Laravel 5.0. Currently due to PHP 7 update, I need to update my Laravel too.

Can I upgrade Laravel 5.7 from Laravel 5.0 directly?
Tel me the step by step process

Comment: No you can't. You have to follow each upgrade process individually.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Please also read [ask] again, your question has much room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There are major changes from 5.0 to 5.7. You cannot upgrade directly from 5.0 to 5.7. You must follow the upgrade guides provided by Laravel step by step.

Or

Since you have many apps to be upgraded, you can save time by using a service like

https://laravelshift.com/

Answer (score 0):

Useful list of all the step by step upgrades

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade (all the steps 4.2 => 5.3)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade (5.3 => 5.4)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade (5.4 => 5.5)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade (5.5 => 5.6)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade (5.6 => 5.7)